# Converting in various currencies

Tags: units, wolfram-alpha-queries, finance

I was just playing around with *Mathematica* converting some currencies:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "\[Euro]"], "ISK"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "\[Euro]"], "£"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "£"], "\[Euro]"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "$"], "\[Euro]"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BitCoin"], "\[Euro]"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BitCoin"], "$"]
```

[image: outputs]

I was surprised about the outputs #23 and #24. Why can't *Mathematica* convert them like the rest?

So I should take the factor BTC/USD:
WolframAlpha says:

[image]

[image]

Why aren't BitCoin rates shown by `UnitConvert`?

And btw: Is there a shortcut for the BitCoin symbol in *Mathematica*?
Here is what I found out about the symbol/shortcut

**EDIT and WARNING:**
Do NOT copy/paste the BitCoin sign (฿) from the output!!! It's not interpreted as Bitcoins by *Mathematica*:

```
Quantity[371.57, "\[Euro]/฿"]
```

[image]

[image]

*Mathematica* gives the same symbol for BitCoin and ThaiBaht!

```
Quantity[1, "฿"]
Quantity[1, "ThaiBaht"]
Quantity[1, "BitCoin"]
```

[image]

BUT

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "฿"], "\[Euro]"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "TahiBaht"], "\[Euro]"]
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BitCoin"], "\[Euro]"]
```

[image]

Comment: 1BTC=478.96 Dol, 1 Dol=0.77Euro -> 478.96*1Dol=478.96*(0.77Euro)=368.06Euro (due to rounding up the numbers). 

Regarding the BTC/USD, I'm no expert, but I'd guess that Wolfram converts the currencies based on the data from an exchange like Forex or CME in which there's only BTC/USD. If you for instance consider Forex, there are currency equities like  EURO/USD, EURO/CHF and so on (so these are actually the products that you trade, they aren't just some fractions!).


In short, it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: " there are currency equities like EURO/USD, EURO/CHF and so on (so these are actually the products that you trade, they aren't just some fractions!)" I do not understand at 100%, but I get an idea. So "BTC/USD" does not mean a factor "1$/1฿" but a "financial product"?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: @GregoryRut Please see my edits: Could it be Mathematica has a very old exchange currency for "฿/\[USD]"?
And might it be "BTC/USD" and "฿/\[USD]" is the same but with currency fluctuation?

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha gives the following information:

[image]

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "$"], "\[Euro]"]
```

> Quantity[0.772082, "Euros"]

```
370.24 / 0.772082
```

> 479.535 (*  USD per BitCoin *)

Actual quotation of one broker: 478.37 USD per BitCoin.

All this is coherent. The only remaining question for me: Why aren't BitCoin rates shown by `UnitConvert`? Maybe because they are highly volatile (even within one day).

Comment: or Bitcoins are no official currency!?

Comment: @Phab There are even legal restrictions in many countries (and many defrauders promising you a 200% return) :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had a mistake. So I should edit my question to your question in your answer :)